# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\products.php on line 148

Tags: php, mysql

```
              <tr>
                <?php include('sql_connect.php'); ?>
              <?php
                $sql="select * from hp";
                $query=mysql_query($sql);

               if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
                { ?>
                  $i=1; 
                   while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($query)
                   {


                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
                    <td class="tm-product-name"><?php echo $hp_model; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $hp_type; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $hp_colour; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $hp_ds; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $hp_price; ?></td>

                  <?php } } ?>

                <td>
                  <a href="#" class="tm-product-delete-link">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt tm-product-delete-icon"></i>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: you are missing to close brace of while loop. while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($query))

Answer (score 1):

> I have updated your code here. so use this below code. you have forgot close this `)` in this line like this while `($row=mysql_fetch_object($query))`

```
<tr>
  <?php include('sql_connect.php'); ?>
  <?php
    $sql="select * from hp";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
    {
      $i=1; 
       while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($query)){ ?>
        <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
        <td class="tm-product-name"><?php echo $hp_model; ?>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo $hp_type; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $hp_colour; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $hp_ds; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $hp_price; ?></td>
  <?php } } ?>
  <td><a href="#" class="tm-product-delete-link"> <i class="far fa-trash-alt tm-product-delete-icon"></i> </a></td>
</tr>
```